# (Beginner) - How to I write decimal calc and print results?

Tags: java

this is the question.

1. Write a Java program to declare two integers and demonstrate the use of
   addition, subtraction, multiplication, division and modulo operators.
2. Repeat the calculations from task 1 using decimal numbers.

---

So I've done part one:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    float a = 4 + 1;
    float b = 484 - 48;
    float c = 484 * 49;
    float d = 32 / 93;
    float e = 55 % 787;

    System.out.print(a + "\n" + b + "\n" + c + "\n" + d + "\n" + e);
}
```

but I'm stuck in part two.

Comment: You actually seem to haven't done part 1 in your snippet. It says "declare two integers", which is variables of type `int`. You are using `float`s.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just replace your numbers with decimals? They're already floats.

Comment: According to your question you are only supposed to hard code _two_ numbers, when you declare them the first time, and then use the variable name for all the calculations.  Reread your question slowly and try to understand what it is asking, because you are not following the directions.

Answer (score 0):

Integers are of type `int`. You are using `float` and declaring 5 variables. Decimal numbers are type `double`

```java
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    int out = a*b;

    System.out.print(out);
}
```

Repeat using doubles

```java
double a = 1.5;
double b = 2.5;
```